# What's stored in data_dir/base of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I suddenly found found my PostgreSQL out of space. It's a tmp instance running on ram disk. Limited space (around 800M) allowed. Data are not actually stored on it, all table will be dropped after some calculation done.

I checked the folder and found tons of data under base folder:

```
$ du -h
6.0M    ./pgsql_tmp
706M    ./16384
6.0M    ./12780
6.0M    ./12772
6.0M    ./1
730M    .
```

My questions are:

- What is inside that folder?
- Any chance I can clean it out?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html

Answer (score 12):

This folder is where PostgreSQL keeps all the data you insert on your databases (see [PostgreSQL Database File Layout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html)). Each sub-directory is used by a database in you cluster, the files inside them are the actual data of the relations (tables, indexes, sequences, ...).

So, your answer is **no**! You cannot clean it out, and if you do so, you will lose your data and PostgreSQL server will stop with a panic.

Basically, only files inside the `pg_log` directory (if any) can be removed. A side note, do not, **ever** remove files inside `pg_xlog`, it is not useless as the name may suggest (you didn't ask for it, but I saw happening sometimes).

**Tips to solve your problem:**

There are some things you can do to use less space in your case, like:

1. Use another (not in RAM) [tablespace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) for some tables or databases;
2. Run a [`VACUUM FULL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY). But notice that you will need some temporary space to do that, so you can't do it while you are really out of space;
3. Move [`pg_xlog`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-internals.html) to another location;
4. As you said it is a temporary database, try to remove some indexes that are not been used.